# C Two Arrays in Struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I want to make a struct with 2 arrays, and I want the user to specify the amount of variables they hold. But I get errors when I run this:

```
typedef struct Image
{
    int amount;
    char* paths[amount];
    SDL_Texture* textures[amount];

} Image;
```

Why am I getting errors and how can I solve them?

Comment: You can't have variable sized arrays like this.

Comment: You apparently need pointers-to-pointers and some dynamic memory management.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Why can't I have that? You do it in for loops right?

Comment: This has nothing to do with loops...

Comment: If `paths` is of a variable size (unknown), where does `textures` begin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have dynamic arrays, you need pointers:

```
typedef struct Image
{
    int amount;
    char** paths;  // pointer to pointer of chars
    SDL_Texture** textures; // pointer to pointer of textures
} Image;
```

When you create a struct object, knowing the real size ("amount") you then allocate memory dynamically:

```
struct Image img;
img.paths = calloc (amount, sizeof(char*)); 
img.textures = calloc (amount, sizeof(SDL_Texture*)); 
img.amount = amount;
```

Of course, you need to check that the allocated poitners are not NULL.

Then you can access to the items as you would have done with your own structure.

***Remark:*** variable length array is an optional feature of the C11 standard. Not every compiler supports it.  But in any case, a `typedef` does never allow for variable length array, because the C compiler needs to know at compile time the size of the whole `struct`. This is only possible if the array size is a constant.

Comment: Any reason for `calloc`?

Comment: Because it simplifies array allocation and it initiates the whole stuff to 0.

Comment: Well, the first one is a valid reason for it, the second as often a reason against it. Also `sizeof *img.path` instead of `sizeof(char*)` is a safer idea.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic array are not authorized in C.
The size has to be know at compilation time.

What you should do here is

```
typedef struct Image
{
    int amount;
    char** paths;
    SDL_Texture** textures;

} Image;

Image* img = (Image*)malloc(sizeof(Image));
img->amount = 42;
img->paths = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * img->amount);
img->textures = (SDL_Texture**)malloc(sizeof(SDL_Texture*) * img->amount);
```